# Name Error: X-Train is not defined Although its defined

Tags: python

I am coding for Logistic regression based neural network. After defining all the sub-functions, I made a model in which these functions are called. But its giving Name Error.

```
   def model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, num_iterations = 2000,     learning_rate = 0.5, print_cost = False):
      Arguments:
      X_train -- training set represented by a numpy array of shape (num_px * num_px * 3, m_train)

      return d

#As the model is called after it is defined,
  d = model(train_set_x, train_set_y, test_set_x, test_set_y, num_iterations = 2000, learning_rate = 0.5, print_cost = True)

 #It gives error
 Name Error:  name 'train_set_x' is not defined. Traceback suggests that the error in  statement which calls function.
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting, this is not valid code.

Comment: Is it fine now ? Sorry I am beginner

Comment: No, now it looks like you are calling the `model` function inside itself which would be an infinite recursion. Please look at the formatting help when asking/editing the question (unfortunately it seems like SO is lacking a preview function?). Also, you should post the _full_ error traceback since as it is now, we have no idea where the error is actually happening

Comment: Yeah I made the changes. Function is called after it is first defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the wrong scope for me? You posted whole thing in a whole snippet, but it looks like you define a function:

```
def model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, num_iterations = 2000,     
          learning_rate = 0.5, print_cost = False):
    X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, classes = load_dataset()
```

and then want to use it?

But notice this: you want the `model` function to *get* the values from somewhere - parameter list is what you get from the outside world, not what you want to return!

`X_model` and the rest are only assigned *in* that function, so calling `d = model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, num_iterations = 2000, learning_rate = 0.5, print_cost = True)` doesn't have X_train, doesn't have Y_train, X_test, Y_test...

Arguments are parsed from left to right, so that's why you get only the first error. But if you do `X_train = None` before the `d=...`, then you'll get the same error message about `Y_train`.

Comment: d =  model(train_set_x, train_set_y, test_set_x, test_set_y, num_iterations =     2000, learning_rate = 0.5, print_cost = True)                                                         Calling with the parameters other than assigned in the function still giving the same error. like name train_set_x  is not defined.

Comment: Yes I defined the function and tried using it, you got that right but the issue is with the name error.

Answer (score 1):

What is a **NameError**? A NameError is raised when you try to use a variable or a function name that is not valid.

In the **model** function, you used variables such as train_set_x, but they weren't predefined.

Simply run the following lines of code to fix this error:(These two lines standardize the data.)

```
train_set_x = train_set_x_flatten / 255.
test_set_x = test_set_x_flatten / 255.
```

You can now use **train_set_x** and other variables in model function.

Comment: Interesting. It sometimes works and sometimes not without these lines. Not sure why! But thank you!

Comment: Just noticed train_set_x and test_set_x are initialized in cell 7, which is preceded by the note below. But for some reason, those variables at the time are not accessible when required! " During the training of your model, you're going to multiply weights and add... "

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me. try running the cell from the beginning to upload the data file

Comment: Is it an answer? What did you do? Please add an example